# text area hidden behind the android keyboard

Tags: android, html, google-chrome

I have a mobile site which has a fixed header and footer. I have a text area field. when I go to write something, the android keyboard pops up and hides the text area.

Any solution for this?

Comment: Are you using a browser, webview app or what? Maybe show us images...

Comment: google chrome on mobile

Comment: getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_VISIBLE|WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_ADJUST_RESIZE);

Comment: What's this @harshal